# How do I refer to a record in sql that immediately precedes another record in a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a weird update query to write.

Here's the table

```
PK-ID (int) --- FK-ID (int) --- Value (int)
```

In my data set, if I group by FK-ID and order by PK-ID, suppose this is an example of one group:

```
5 --- 10 --- 23
7 --- 10 --- 49
8 --- 10 --- 81
```

Due to a bug in some old software, records 7 and 8 have incorrect values. The correct value for 7 is (49-23) = 26 and the correct value for 8 is (81-49) = 32. Record 5 is correct.

I need to update each record to subtract the value of the record immediately preceding it when it is grouped by FK-ID and ordered by PK-ID. If there is no preceding record I do not need to change the value.

Is there a way to write a general sql update query to accomplish this? How would I (conditionally) retrieve the value of the preceding record in the group? I'm using SQL server 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: What is RDMS? If it supports window functions , you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` or `RANK() OVER` ...

Comment: Is it possible to offset this into a java/c++ process that would do this comparison logic, then execute a batch statement back to the server to perform an update?

Comment: yes I could certainly perform this in a higher level language but I'm really curious to see if sql can do it. I have to do this every night too, and I already have a huge set of sql scripts I can add this to. Don't want to add more programs to the nightly process

Comment: Well the question I now have is, if this is something that needs to be run nightly why is the problem code not being fixed?  I understand this is an interim solution.  Also, SQL can certainly do this, the maintenance of it is what becomes problematic.

Comment: no need to fix the problem code, the whole program it is in is being replaced.

Comment: so when the day comes that the old program is thrown out, the nightly scripts are run for the last time. currently the nightly scripts prepare a fixed database to test the new program against.

Comment: thanks everyone for helping me. I'm not at all fluent in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with ordered as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by fk_id order by pk_id)
      from tbl
    )
update cur
   set value = cur.value - prior.value
  from ordered cur
  join ordered prior on prior.fk_id = cur.fk_id
                and prior.rn = cur.rn-1;
```

Comment: strangely it set all my values to zero

Comment: although it appeared when i selected the results of your join that it should have grabbed the right value.

Comment: this did work, i just mistakenly went update table instead of update cur, thats why it set everything to zero initially.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I believe to be the correct answer, using a similar idea to the previous one.  The toupdate subquery calculates the values, based on the rules in the question (update records with the same foreign key and consecutive primary keys).  It does assume that the ids are nuemric values of some sort.

```
with toupdate as (
    select t.pkid, t.value - tprev.value as newval
    from t join
         t tprev
         on t.pkid = tprev.pkid+1 and t.fkid = tprev.fkid
   )
update t
    set value = newvalue
    from toupdate
    where t.pkid = toupdate.pkid
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it should return what you want(sorry, I cannot try it the moment); you just need to incorporate it with `UPDATE`

```
 WITH cte1 AS 
 (SELECT pk_id, fk_id, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk_id ORDER BY pk_id DESC)
 as num 
 FROM your_table 
 )

 SELECT a.*, 
 --CASE 
 --  WHEN b.pk_id IS NOT NULL THEN a.value-b.value 
 --  ELSE 0 END 
 a.value-b.value as valid_number
 FROM cte1 a
 --LEFT JOIN cte1 b ON (b.fk_id = a.fk_id AND b.num = a.num-1)
 INNER JOIN cte1 b ON (b.fk_id = a.fk_id AND b.num = a.num-1)
```

Comment: Should be INNER JOIN not left join. First record is correct, it has a value of 23. Only the next two are wrong, since they accummulated.

Comment: @ RichardTheKiwi : Oops, I either got '0' from somewhere else, or the question was updated - I was sure OP asked to change it to 0 if no prev records. Surely, it has to `INNER JOIN` if no such requirements. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't have time to try it but you'll get an upvote for the effort

Answer (score 1):

```
update t set value = value -
              isnull((select top 1 value 
                                 from t t2 
                                     where t2.FKID=t.FKID 
                                       and t2.PKID<t.PKID 
                        order by PKID desc),0);
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6605f/1)

Comment: sorry i don't have time to try your solution. But thanks for helping me